# Euler Method Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have written very simple Python code to solve the simple harmonic oscillator using Euler method, but I am not sure if the program is correct or not. I would be very grateful if anyone can look at my code and suggest further improvements since I am very new to this programming thing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
v=0.0   #initial velocity
h=0.01  #time step
x=5.0   #initial position

t=0.0
ta,xa=[],[]

while t<1.0:
    ta.append(t)
    xa.append(x)

    v=v-(10.0/1.0)*x*h    #k=10.0, m=1.0
    x=x+v*h
    t=t+h
plt.figure()
plt.plot(ta,xa,'--')
plt.xlabel('$t(s)$')
plt.ylabel('$x(m)$')
plt.show()
```

Comment: In what sense is this the "Euler" method? It just looks like a discrete-timestep simulation to me.

Comment: For dy/dx=f(x,y), we can find the value of y at x1=x0+h as y(x1)=y(x0)+hf(x0,y0)$. Isn't this what the Euler's method precisely about ?

Comment: I don't see what role does `g` play. Besides, `h` is really `dt`. That said, it is far from harmonic oscillator.

Comment: Yes, it seems I did a mistake by calling variable g which is not needed for this one since I was doing free fall motion earlier. So, haven't I used the Euler method correctly in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is quite monolithic: calculation and presentation are separate concerns, and while I appreciate the context given by showing the presentation, it would be better to make clear that they're separate concerns by separating them with whitespace and commenting briefly.

Also on structure: separate constants (`h`) from variables (`v`, `x`, `t`).

---

> ```
>     v=v-(10.0/1.0)*x*h    #k=10.0, m=1.0
>     x=x+v*h
>     t=t+h
> ```

Two things: firstly, what are `k` and `m`? It seems that they should be constants with comments explaining their physical significance.

Secondly, this isn't Euler's method. Euler's method is \$\vec{x}_{n+1} = \vec{x}_n + hf(t_n, \vec{x}_n)\$ where \$f = \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}\$. Here \$\vec{x} = (v, x)\$ and \$f(t, v, x) = (\frac{dv}{dt}, \frac{dx}{dt}) = (-\frac{k}{m}x, v)\$. In other words, to be Euler's method you should update `x` according to the *previous* value of `v`, not the *updated* value of `v`. Since you're using Python, you can take advantage of simultaneous assignment:

```
    v,x=v-(k/m)*x*h,x+v*h
    t=t+h
```

(As it happens your buggy implementation works better than Euler's method, but if it was intended to implement Euler's method then it's still technically buggy).

Comment: Thanks @Taylor. I would definitely take that into consideration, and I should have updated x first.

Comment: @RoshanShrestha, no, that would be equally wrong. You should update them *simultaneously*, which depending on the language may mean using temporary variables.

Comment: But, I have used temporary variables for x,v and t outside the while loop. So, does it mean that if I order my code for Euler method x=x+v*h                                                                            v=v-(10.0/1.0)*x*h     will still be wrong ?

Comment: @RoshanShrestha, I wouldn't call those [temporary variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_variable). Also, I've realised that the code is Python (I had initially misread and thought it was Matlab, which I don't know), so that means it supports simultaneous assignment. I've edited sample code into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is well working code, although it's not Euler algorithm - it's Euler-Cromer (if you want to make sure it's showing cos function just make the maximum `t` in your `while` more 2 or 3 will do the thing)

Euler method uses current velocity for the next x, so you need to change the places of those

`v=v-(10.0/1.0)*x*h` with `x=x+v*h`

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You typed `"cos"` - is that intended to be "_because_", or (trigonometric function) _cosine_?